# How to write C# method to return a List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is an on-going exercise from my previous question "List joins DataTable".

I want to write a method that return a List. In my example below, the intellisence does not recognize "return query;".

Can you please advise what I am doing wrong here?

---

```
public List<CodeName> CodeNameList()
{
    List<CodeName> lst = new List<CodeName>();
    lst.Add(new CodeName { code = "1", name = "x" });
    lst.Add(new CodeName { code = "2", name = "y" });
    lst.Add(new CodeName { code = "3", name = "z" });

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add("3", "a");
    dt.Rows.Add("4", "b");
    dt.Rows.Add("5", "c");

    var query = (from l in lst
                join d in dt.AsEnumerable() on l.code equals d.Field<string>("code")
                select new { l.code, l.name}).ToList();

    return query;
}

public class CodeName
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're selecting `new { l.code, l.name }` - that isn't a `CodeName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason the `var` keyword was introduced alongside LINQ. It's because a LINQ query will often return an *anonymous type* - a type that's created ad-hoc as part of your query, that isn't an explicitly defined type, and thus, `var` allows you to specify a variable of that type.

This is what happens here. Your LINQ query creates a collection of an anonymous type that has two fields, `code` and `name`, that's created ad-hoc in your select statement:
`select new {l.code, l.name}`. So your `query` variable isn't a a `List<CodeName>`, but a `List<[unprintable anonymous type]>`. The fact that the anonymous type is structurally identical to `CodeName` doesn't matter, because C# is a strictly typed language and wants the types to be the same *declared* type.

You can easily fix it by creating a new `CodeName` in your query, instead of the anonymous type, and the Object Initializer syntax even makes it easy:

```
var query = (from l in lst
            join d in dt.AsEnumerable() on l.code equals d.Field<string>("code")
            select new CodeName { code = l.code, name = l.name}).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello Avner, thanks for explaining the root cause of the problem-- much appreciated this.

Comment: Hello Avner, thanks for explaining the root cause of the problem-- much appreciated this.

Now that the method returns List<CodeName>. I want to call it from the Main method like this

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<CodeName> ls = CodeNameList();
}

The intellisence warns with message "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property Program.CodeNameList()"

Can you please advise?

Comment: This is a separate issue and should be asked separately. However, I would warn you that it's a very basic issue of static/instance methods, which I would recommend reading up on before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a List, but not a List< Codename > - you can modify the "new" part like this:

```
            var query = (from l in lst
                     join d in dt.AsEnumerable() on l.code equals d.Field<string>("code")
                     select new CodeName { code = l.code, name = l.name }).ToList();
```